# SPARQL Protege Plugin Error on Importing

Tags: maven, plugins, sparql, protege

I'm writing a plug-in for [Protege](https://github.com/protegeproject/protege) that uses the `BasicSPARQLReasoner` provided by the SPARQL Protege plug-in. I'm using the last version provided by Maven artifact ID [`sparql-query-plugin`](https://github.com/protegeproject/sparql-query-plugin), version `2.0.2`. Now if I use the class --

```
BasicSparqlReasoner reasoner=new BasicSparqlReasoner(editorKit.getOWLModelManager().getOWLOntologyManager());
```

When I load the plug-in created i receive the following error by Protege:

```
missing requirement [protege.plugin.YASPP [30](R 30.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (&
       (osgi.wiring.package=org.protege.editor.owl.rdf.repository)(version>=5.0.0))
at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.resolveBundleRevision(Felix.java:4133) ~[org.apache.felix.main.jar:na]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:2118) ~[org.apache.felix.main.jar:na]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.setActiveStartLevel(Felix.java:1372) ~[org.apache.felix.main.jar:na]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.FrameworkStartLevelImpl.run(FrameworkStartLevelImpl.java:308) [org.apache.felix.main.jar:na]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_40]
```

The SPARQL plug-in works fine alone inside Protege. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok the problem is in other maven artifacts included in the project.